# Selenium with java add generic logger for extended reports in ThreadLocal

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a generic logger class to add a log to the extended reports from anywhere in the project, not just tests, but also page objects.

I have this base implementation

```
package utilities.reports.Listeners;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import utilities.reports.BaseTest;
import utilities.reports.ExtentManager;

public class TestListener extends BaseTest implements ITestListener {

    //Extent Report Declarations
    private static ExtentReports extent = ExtentManager.createInstance();
    public static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> test = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public synchronized void onStart(ITestContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        extent.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        ExtentTest extentTest = extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName(), result.getMethod().getDescription());
        test.set(extentTest);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        test.get().pass("Test passed");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        test.get().fail(result.getThrowable());
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        test.get().skip(result.getThrowable());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
    }

    //Method for adding logs passed from test cases
    public static void reportLog(String message) {
        test.get().pass(message);//For extentTest HTML report
    }
}
```

But when I try to access the test to add a report I get nullPointer

```
 public static void logInfo(String message) {
        test.get().info(message);
    }
```

Any ideas on how I can implement a simple logger class for adding info to the extended reports.